# Unable to start GNU/Linux installation process while installing from USB

Tags: linux, installation, freeze, liveusb, usb-boot

I use Trisquel GNU/Linux 7.0. I am trying to install it on my uncle's desktop-pc (running with Windows7 currently) from (bootable) USB.

The scenario is: I plug USB stick, choose boot from USB, choose "Try Trisquel without Installing" or "Install Trisquel", when desktop displays I choose install Trisquel (in case of try without installing) and while going with (for both case) step-by-step wizard it hangs within a minute. Sometimes at 1<sup>st</sup> step language-selection, sometimes at 2<sup>nd</sup> step, hardly I can reach to selection of partition and it hangs. Hence I am unable to start the installation process.

I've tried three-times burning USB with different ways viz. `usb-creator-gtk`, [universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), and `sudo dd if=/path/to/trisquel_7.0_i686.iso of=/dev/sdc`, also tried formatting USB with FAT32, NTFS, also tried with 3 different slot that pc has for USB plug; but all the times It (mostly) boots fine but facing above mentioned problem.

Note that there is no such problem if I run USB in my pc. So, I think there might be some compatibility problem with hardware or booting-configuration. That pc is simple desktop-pc with no extra graphics card (integrated only) and 1GB of RAM. Also note that pc has no problems with current system and working fine but unfortunately don't has CD/DVD ROM and that's why I am trying to install from USB.

So, Is there any workaround? Any configuration/option that I can change for getting rid of this problem and have a smooth installation?

Comment: Which language are you installing in? I suggest trying English for once! I had a similar problem with also Ubuntu-based Linux Mint, where the installer has a problem installing in any other language but English. You can change the language for menus and windows from English to another language in System Settings after you have installed Trisquel.

Comment: @TJJ Already using English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the following options (provided to configure [kernel options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options) by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> at the staring screen) helped me:

```
acpi=off
noapic
nolapic
edd=on
nodmraid
nomodeset
```

And today I successfully installed Trisquel GNU/Linux 7.0